# Get the id from url

Tags: python, list

I would like to get the id from the url ,I have stored a set of urls in a list,i would like to get a certail part of the url ,ie is the id part ,for thoose url that dont have an id part should print as none.The code so far i have tried

```
text=[u'/fhgj/b?ie=UTF8&node=2858778011',u'/gp/v/w/', u'/gp/v/l', u'/gp/fhghhgl?ie=UTF8&docId=1001423601']
text=text.rsplit(sep='&', maxsplit=-1)
print text
```

the output is

```
 [u'2858778011',u'/gp/v/w/', u'/gp/v/l', u'1001423601']
```

i expect to get something like this

```
[u'2858778011',u'None', u'None', u'1001423601']
```

Comment: Is that really your code? I didn't think you could do `rsplit` on a list object; I'm not sure that `rsplit` allows keyword arguments; and also, splitting text at the '&' symbol wouldn't get rid of the `node=` part.

Comment: Also, how do you determine which value has the ID you want? i.e. you want the `node` value in the first one and the `docID` in the last.

Answer (score 0):

Use `urlparse`, or if you really want to use string libs then

```
prefix, sep, text = text.partition("&")
```

(or just `text = text.partition("&")[2]`).

Comment: That's going to give you the bit after the "&" symbol, eg "node=2858778011".

Comment: Isn't that what was asked for? Well, ignoring the several errors in the post.

Comment: His expected output was "2858778011" so I took that to mean that he just wanted the part after the "=". Might be worth expanding your answer to show how `urlparse` could be used.